# Setting Random Name to Button in Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms, random

I am trying to create Memory puzzle game. I want to set image to button randomly on form load. But i am not able to achieve it.

I am trying to assign random number to 20 buttons in my form,and assign them image randomly based on number.

This is what i tried.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button button = new Button();
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int number = 0;

    foreach (Control item in Controls)
    {
        number = rnd.Next(1, 20);
        button.Name = number.ToString();
    }

    if (button.Name == 1.ToString() || button.Name == 2.ToString())
    {
       Icon myIcon = (Icon)Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(
                         @"C:\Users\richa\Desktop\Goat.png");
       button.Image = myIcon.ToBitmap();
    }
}
```

**Also am i setting image in right way on Button??**

Comment: try `button.Text` instead of `button.Name`

Comment: @chouaib I don't want to show text on button

Comment: see my answer bellow

Comment: First you need to create buttons and add to Form's control collection. From above code it seems that only one button is created and it is not added to Forms controls, if you are creating button dynamically. Also, above code what is purpose of using foreach loop?

Comment: @Amit I have just started learning Windows form. I have created 20 button on form. How do i add to form's control collection

Comment: Just use this.Controls.Add(myButton); refer for more detail -http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16682/Dynamically-Adding-Button-to-a-Form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you can use `Tag`:

```
button.Tag = number.ToString();
```

and

```
Convert.ToInt32(button.Tag) == 1
```

**EDIT**

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    bool[] used = new bool[20];
    int number = 0;

    // if you have your buttons created in a container (groupbox for example)
    foreach (var btn in container.Controls)
    {
         number = rnd.Next(1, 20);
         while(used[number])
         {
            number = rnd.Next(1,20);
         }
         ((Button)btn).Tag = number.ToString();
         used[number] = true;

         // add goat.png to your resources beforehand
         // right click your project --> properties --> resources --> add resource --> add existing file --> select goat.png, and rename it to GoatImg
         if (number == 1 || number == 2)
         {
            btn.Image = Properties.Resources.GoatImg;
         }
    }

}
```

Comment: The problem is in foreach i guess, i want all 20 button to have separate id or text. But i guess it is setting same text or name to all button

Comment: @Richa, see edit, you will now set different ID for each button, then check if its ID is `1` or `2` and assign an image

Comment: Random.Next(1,20) doesn't guarantee that you will get 20 different numbers over 20 iterations.

Comment: @RohitPrakash: that's why I used the infinite loop `while(used[number])` ;)

Comment: @chouaib Thanks. But now the image is not setting. I guess something is wrong with image setting

Comment: @chouaib, still an infinite loop is not suggested. Instead you can use ordering numbers with a GUID, best suited for sequential random number generator.

Comment: @RohitPrakash, so it was not guaranteed then it turned out to be not suggested! not suggested by whom? did we have suggestions by the OP above? I guess it is US who are eligible to suggest here! anyway if you have some improvements I am always so glad to learn more

Comment: @Richa, I edited the answer, see how you can change the images in an *easy* way

Comment: @chouaib, This is not about who suggested what. When it comes to an iteration, one has to think about the best iteration pattern. In this case, this is OK because it has 20 numbers only. but it might throw stackoverflow exception once it goes for 100000000 iterations.

Comment: @RohitPrakash, **NO** noway for `StackOverFlowException` in this example, the iterator just keep checking if this number is already found and move on, I agree with you if you said it takes longer time for a bigger set (that's a bit matter of optimization which really doesn't matter in this question), btw does my answer really deserve a -1?

Answer (score 2):

You should have an array of the buttons, and an array of the possible images to randomize:

```
public void PutRandomImagesOnButtons(Button[] buttons, Bitmap[] images)
{
    var rand = new Random();

    foreach (var btn in buttons)
    {
        btn.BackgroundImage = images[rand.Next(images.Length)];
    }
}
```

For a newbie, I'd suggest create the 20 buttons manually, and then create the array with the following code:

```
private Button[] _btns;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this._btns = new Button[]
                 {
                     this.btn1, this.btn2, this.btn3, ...
                 };
}
```

Apply the same logic to have the array of images and call `PutRandomImagesOnButtons(this._btns, this._images)` at the end (or whenever you want, really).

For more advanced reading, search for dynamically creating and adding controls, and inevitably about the `FlowLayoutPanel` which helps you arranging dynamic controls.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287574%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

http://visualcsharptutorials.com/windows-forms/dynamically-adding-controls

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NxfYFAw0JDs

Answer (score -2):

you can use the guid ordering.

```
        Dictionary<int, Guid> dic = new Dictionary<int, Guid>();
        int i = 0;
        while (i < 20)
        {
            dic.Add(i, Guid.NewGuid());
            i++;
        }
        // Now order by the guid.
        var newDic = dic.OrderByDescending(item => item.Value).ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Value, kvp => kvp.Key);

        int iSetter = 0;
        foreach (Control item in Controls)
        {
            Button button = new Button();
            int number = newDic.ElementAt(iSetter++).Value;
            button.Name = number.ToString();

            if (button.Name == 1.ToString() || button.Name == 2.ToString())
            {
                Icon myIcon = (Icon)Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(@"C:\Users\richa\Desktop\Goat.png");
                button.Image = myIcon.ToBitmap();
            }

            Controls.Add(button);
        }
```